# how to fill the method public boolean checkAnswer(String response)?

Tags: java, oop, boolean, return

I need help to see what i am doing wrong here. The Instructions are:

1. use StringTokenizer on getAnswer ;
2. while it hasMoreTokens ;
3. check if response matches the nextToken ;
4. return true if it does ;
5. return false if none do.

This is what i have coded:

```
public boolean checkAnswer{
 StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(getAnswer());
    while (str.hasMoreTokens()){
        if(response.matches(str.nextToken())) return true;
    }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `if(!response.equals(str.nextToken()))return false;` You don't need this inside while loop. you just need `return false;` after completion of while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will be parsed as

```
public boolean checkAnswer {
 StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(getAnswer());
    while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if(response.equals(str.nextToken())) return true;
    }

    if(!response.equals(str.nextToken()))return false;
}
```

Which is not what you need to do according to your specification (and probably is neither what you intended to do while you wrote it) and it neither returns a boolean on every branch (since Javac won't look if branches are exhaustive for non trivial cases.

Comment: Just to get this straight. What i did is not correct from what is being asked in the instructions?

Comment: Yes, because you are returning true if a token matches and false if token doesn't match. See Emil Lundberg answer, you should return false just when all tokens don't match the your answer. You should never return false from checking a single token.

Comment: I have edited to what I believe is what you're trying to tell me. Can you inform me if i'm still not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You want to return `false` if none of the tokens equals `response`. This is the case if and only if your `while` loop exits. See also @Jack's answer.